# Creación de escuchador KeyListener para calculadora simple

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos, java-awt

He creado un MVC para una calculadora simple, en el cual  creo un Objeto de la clase `CalcuController` donde tengo `implements ActionListener, KeyListener`. Todos los métodos declarados.

La cuestión es que **no recoge el escuchador de pulsación de números del teclado**.

Expongo un trozo de mi código, me interesa saber donde estoy fallando y por qué.

```
public CalcuController(JTextField pantalla) {
    this.pantalla = pantalla;
    //this.teclaPulsada = teclaPulsada;
    modal = new CalcuModal();
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    int codigo = e.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println(codigo+" Typed");
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int codigo = e.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println(codigo+" Pressed");
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int codigoR = e.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println(codigoR +" Released");

}
```

Esa es la clase `CalcuController implement ActionListener, KeyListener` y su constructor de `CalcuController` donde recibe el parámetro del texto que hay en el display ( `pantalla.getText()` ).
tengo un objeto modal que llama a las operaciones pero no me interesa.
lo que me interesa es que una vez hago ejecución del ejercicio, no reacciona a ninguna tecla.
Esto tengo expuesto en la clase `CalcuView` :

```
public void escuchadorKeyButton() {
    tecladoNumerico = new CalcuController(pantalla);
    addKeyListener(tecladoNumerico);
}
```

Entonces, si yo le asigno el `JButon` `boton1.addKeyListener();` solo reacciona si pincho con el mouse en el botón 1, una vez pulsado ya puedo pulsar cualquier tecla que me lo imprime el código que es, tanto si es `Press`, `Type`  o `Release`.

Comment: Tienes que publicar el código como texto, no imagenes.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, lo editaré

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que no te imprime nada si oprimes teclase de la sección conocida como "bloque numérico" en un teclado completo?

Comment: Si, eso es. Lo que me pasa es como si no tuviera foco o pierde foco. He intentado el foco en JFrame pero algo hago mal que no lo realiza, y si solo se lo asigno a un JButton pues solo funciona ahí, por eso expuse la pregunta. Muchas gracias por la editación.

Answer (score -2):

tengo un problema similar ahora mismo, estoy aprendiendo java e intento hacer una calculadora con keylistener solo que sin interfaz grafica sino en consola.

No tengo idea de si te ayude, pero tengo la hipotesis de que si codificamos la operacion con un switch dentro de "Keypressed" segun el codigo del boton que se presione (como +, -, *, /) para cada caso y que vaya reescribiendo el valor de las variables de tu clase e irlas imprimiendo en el main.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Haz el [tour] para saber cómo funciona el sitio y lee [answer]: la sección de respuestas es para las propuestas de solución, no para comentarios tales como _tengo el mismo problema_. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás dejar comentarios, y si realmente tienes algún problema con algún código en particular, formula una nueva pregunta, leyendo [ask].